# Apostrophe `s` and adjective

Tags: adjectives, apostrophe

I'm a bit confused if I can use adjective after a noun with apostrophe `s`.

```
I broke Jim's fragile figure.
I broke fragile figure of Jim.
```

For example, which of these two sentences is correct?

Comment: Without other context, I would interpret "Jim's fragile figure" to mean a figure owned by Jim, while "*the* fragile figure of Jim" would be interpreted as "a figure in the likeness of Jim" Both are correct grammatically (with the '*the*' of course) it just depends on which meaning you intend.

Comment: Not so much of a question. This construct is used all the time and can be seen often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use an adjective after a possessive noun.  The item that belongs to the noun with the "apostrophe `s`" needn't be the very next word.  For example, I could say that:

> My day was worse than [Alexander's](http://images.indiebound.com/732/711/9780689711732.jpg) terrible, horrible, no good, very bad day.

and it would be obvious that the *'s* at the end of *Alexander's* referred to *day*, not to *terrible*.

So, as Jim said in his comment, there's nothing wrong with:

> I broke Jim's fragile figure.

although maybe you should be more careful with his fragile stuff from now on ;^)